# Adding delegate to IBDesignable class causes UI not to render

Tags: swift, ibdesignable

I have a IBDesignable class I am working on, and I have noticed that if I try to add a protocol to the class, it causes an error "Failed to render and update autolayout status"

If I take the protocol out, it works fine, however for some of the functions I will be trying to create, this would be very useful. Example code you can use to recreate the error

```
import UIKit

protocol TestProtocol {}

@IBDesignable class TestDesignableButton: UIButton {        
    var delegate: TestProtocol?
}
```

Does anyone know what causes this? And do you know if there is a way around this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a bug that occurs often with `IBDesignable`s. I just avoid using them due to their bugginess.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the error? The IBDesignable class still works with the delegate method in place. I can run the app and it looks fine, just the UI element just does not show in storyboard properly when I add the delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your protocol declaration to:

```
@objc protocol TestProtocol {}
```

Here it is, working in my tests (I changed your code a little, but not much — just enough make sure we have the bare bones working). Note that designable button is in fact green; it wouldn't be if the IBDesignable code were not working. Also it says "Up to date" in the inspector at the right.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, such a simple fix. Cheers for your help!